# Magento layered product collection

Tags: magento

How to get filtered products collection ids in extention.
For current category we just getting **Mage::registry('current_category')->getProductCollection()->getAllIds()**, and how we can retrive already filtered product collection (really not product collection, but all  already filtered product Ids)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For getting already filtered product collection You can use following code:

```
$filteredList = $this->getLayout()
        ->getBlockSingleton('catalog/product_list')
        ->getLoadedProductCollection();
```

This code should be executed from within a block.

Comment: Thnx. Really I even didn't think to get this data over layout

Comment: That returns only products from current page. Is it possible to get all loaded products from all pages. Total product collection was 16 but as i am in page 1, it returned only count 10 for me.